# Need to properly iterate through my picture array angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

So I have this function that is a 'next' button that is supposed to go to the next picture in my array. I have also a 'previous' button that has basically the same code but instead of index adding 1 it subtracts 1. That works fine. But this one won't work. When I hit the next button it automatically goes to the last picture in the array and doesn't see the next image. I thought maybe using the pop method but I am not sure, very new to this

```
export class PictureModalComponent {
  model = {
    servNum: '',
    servDate: '',
    caption: '',
    url: '',
    id: null,
    pictures: []
  };

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PictureModalComponent>) {
    this.model=data;
  }

  onPreviousClick() {
    this.model.pictures.forEach( (picture: AccessApictures, index: number) => {
      if (picture.id === this.model.id)
        {
          let lastPicture: AccessApictures = this.model.pictures[index-1];
          this.model.caption = lastPicture.caption;
          this.model.servDate = lastPicture.servDate;
          this.model.servNum = lastPicture.aservrecno;
          this.model.url = lastPicture.filename;
          this.model.id = lastPicture.id;
        }
    });
  }

  onNextClick() {

    this.model.pictures.forEach( (picture: AccessApictures, index: number) => {
      if (picture.id === this.model.id ) {
        let nextPicture: AccessApictures = this.model.pictures[index+1];

        this.model.caption = nextPicture.caption;
        this.model.servDate = nextPicture.servDate;
        this.model.servNum = nextPicture.aservrecno;
        this.model.url = nextPicture.filename;
        this.model.id =  nextPicture.id;
      }
    }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (picture.id === this.model.id )`. Could this be the reason why? Maybe the picture id is different from the model ID, which is causing them to be skipped over.

If possible, could you please post more of your code. It's hard to know for sure what's going on here without some context.

Comment: yes will update now

Comment: Hey I updated it with more code. @nmg49

Comment: Can you post a console.log of your model?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'caption' of undefined"  that is the error but it is due to the nextPicture being undefined not caption

Comment: Well that's your issue... Your next item in the model is undefined. The issue is most likely coming from the source of your model, rather than any code posted here.

Comment: it is because it is reaching the end of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an `index` variable should help you by removing your costly loops. It's basically 2 bytes that will save your performance.

```
index = 0;
model = {
   servNum: '',
   servDate: '',
   caption: '',
   url: '',
   id: null,
   pictures: []
};

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PictureModalComponent>) {
  this.model = data;
  data.pictures.forEach((pic, index) =>  {
     if (pic.id === data.id) {
       this.index = index;
       break;
    }
  }
}

// update index with looping to the last picture if on first
onPreviousClick() {
  this.index = this.index === 0 ? this.model.pictures.length - 1 : this.index - 1;
  this.updateModel(this.model.pictures[this.index]);
}

// updating index with looping to the first picture if on last
onNextClick() {
  this.index = this.index === this.model.pictures.length - 1 ? 0 : this.index + 1; 
  this.updateModel(this.model.pictures[this.index]);
}

// common logic into a single function
updateModel(pic: AccessApictures) {
  this.model.caption = pic.caption;
  this.model.servDate = pic.servDate;
  this.model.servNum = pic.aservrecno;
  this.model.url = pic.filename;
  this.model.id = pic.id;
}
```